# Fix Overscan/ Underscan on HDTV Intel HD Graphics Card

Tags: 12.10, display, resolution, intel, hdmi

I have my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10 hooked up via HDMI to my 24inch, 1080p HDTV though I am experiencing an overscan problem. When the tv cis connected, it cannot be run at the 1080x720 resolution (on display settings within ubuntu) as the TV cuts off about 10% of each side and corner on the HDTV.

The only way I can get a full picture/ proper resolution is to change the resolution (within Ubuntu's display settings) for the HDTV to 1366x768 (same as the laptop's screen settings)

Unfortunately, there is no option on my remote/tv to adjust the overscan settings manually and was hoping there was a way to gain full control of these settings within Ubuntu to gain a proper resolution on the HDTV with the HDMI cable.

When I run windows, I am able to use the 'intel catalyst control centre' to adjust the overscan/underscan from within windows, and that works fine. Is there something like this (preferably with a GUI interface)

Thanks